# Emulator not starting in Hyper-V VM

Tags: android-studio, hyper-v

I am setting up an Android Studio on my Hyper-V Windows 10 VM
It just shows black blank screen. I don't see any errors on console as well.
Everything is working fine except when I fire up my AVD, it is just not starting. 
Here is the screenshot of it:
 1. I enabled nested virtualization 
 2. Audio and Microphones are also available
 3. Java SDK installed
 4. Android SDK is also installed
 5. HAXM 7.3.2 installed and enabled
 6. Java Path is set as environment variable

[image: Emulator not startting]